# How can I fix my sound on an Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02) ALC662?

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I am running Arch Linux. There is no sound coming from this card, despite a driver "snd_hda_intel" having been loaded. Sounds is coming out of the left speaker.

I've googled this and I have found that other people are having issues:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1858638
- http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse/discussions/1/648814842621135143/
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036508
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/43628/no-sound-with-intel-82801i-audio
- https://superuser.com/questions/912553/no-sound-on-arch-linux-alsa

So I thought I would open a question on stackexchange for this issue.

### uname -rnm

```
arch 4.2.5-1-ARCH x86_64
```

### grep -i audio

(I only care about the 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller.)

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
```

### lshw -c multimedia

(I only care about the 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller.)

```
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:fdcfc000-fdcfffff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff
```

### aplay -l

(I only care about the 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller.)

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

### amixer sset Master unmute

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 43 [67%] [-21.00dB] [on]
```

### alsamixer

[image]

Comment: Did you check [pulseaudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting)?

Comment: @Braiam Please be more specific.

Comment: I see a lot of hardware information, but none about the software part of stuff. I don't even know if you checked that the volume isn't 0 or muted...

Comment: @Braiam I hopefully cleared up any doubts of mute issues.